# Why do we have more than one texture?

Tags: forces, atoms

Say I rest my hand on a wooden desk. My hand does not go through the desk because my hand is made up of atoms and as is the desk. The atoms in my hand repel the atoms of the desk when I rest my hand on said desk.

My question is that isnt this force of repulsion the same regardless of the material upon which I rest my hand? How come I have different feelings in my hand based on the material I am touching?

Not sure if I should be posting this biology stack exchange.

Comment: I would argue the difference in textures comes from sliding your hand across the surface rather than just resting your hand on the surface.

Answer (score 3):

No, the force of repulsion would not be exactly the same for different materials.  That is very much not the case.

On the molecular level, different materials will react differently to force, because the intermolecular reactions which determine the net force will depend on what molecules are reacting and how they are oriented.

For an obvious example, compare a rubber mat to a steel mat.  You put pressure on a rubber mat, and it will deform a lot; do it to a steel mat and you won't even be able to notice the compression, it is so small in comparison.  They will feel quite a bit different because they react differently to forces on the molecular level (along with other differences in surface texture).

On a more macroscopic scale, it should be apparent that different surfaces have different textures.  A bumpy surface will feel bumpy because the surface is not even, so when you push down, different parts of your finger get pushed more than others, and that difference will give a sensation you can feel.  Smoother surfaces will also resist motion across the less; due to less interactions between the objects moving relative to each other.